# Order of selected options

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to make a plugin that would allow my users to add tags to their topics. My idea was to use just regular select with multiple atribute like this:

```html
  <form id="multiselect" method="post" action="foo.php">
    <select id="tags" name="tag_id[]" multiple="multiple">
 <option value="1">Tag 1</option>
 <option value="2">Tag 2</option>
 <option value="3">Tag 3</option>
 <option value="4">Tag 4</option>
 <option value="5">Tag 5</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="button">
</form>
```

however I wanna be able to add them in the order that user selected them... e.g. if someone would have selected 2,4,1 I wanna be able to add those tags in the exact same order. The problem is that the array( `print_r($_POST["tag_id"]);` )  is sorted by options as they are in the select, not in the order user selected them. What's the best approach so that I can work with the order in PHP?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it directly.  You will need to do this with javascript. Keep a stack and whenever the value of `#tags` changes do following :

- remove unselected elements from stack (if any in stack)
- push newly selected elements into the stack.

Here I shown the implementation with jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var tags = [];
    $("#tags").change(function(e) {
        var val = $("#tags").val();
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            if(val.indexOf(tags[i]) == -1){
                tags.splice(i,1);
                i--;
            }
        }
        for(i in val){
            if(tags.indexOf(val[i]) == -1){
                tags.push(val[i]);
            }
        }
        alert(tags);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="multiselect" method="post" action="foo.php">
    <select id="tags" name="tag_id[]" multiple="multiple">
 <option value="1">Tag 1</option>
 <option value="2">Tag 2</option>
 <option value="3">Tag 3</option>
 <option value="4">Tag 4</option>
 <option value="5">Tag 5</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="button">
</form>
```

And then you can put this array in any **hidden** type `input` to be used at server side.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the order of user click and submit that along with the selection data. When you display the tags, order by the field you captured earlier.